# How do I make sure the Software Updater App isn't running?

Tags: apt, update-manager

How do I make sure the Software Updater App isn't running?

Installing Ubuntu on a Virtual Box.

Trying to install GIT

```
$ sudo apt install git
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Disregard...  Closed my terminal and found the Update App wanting to install an update.  Ubuntu 1 - me 0.

Answer (score 1):

As per [your own comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1106609/timeline#comment_1825448):

> Close your terminal and find the Update App wanting to install an update.